# React native: Race condition between 2 fresco initialization

Tags: react-native, configuration, fresco

We want to custom our own `ExecutorSupplier` in Fresco for profiling purposes. We call `FrescoModule.getDefaultConfigBuilder(reactContext)` first to get default config builder and set ExecutorSupplier on the builder.

Since `FrescoModule.getDefaultConfigBuilder(reactContext)` need us to provide `ReactContext`, so we call it after we are notified inside `ReactInstanceEventListener`. Then we invoke `Fresco.initialize(application, imagePipelineConfig)` to initialize it.

But we found a race condition between the Fresco initialization within ReactNative and Fresco we tried to initialize by Fresco.initialize(). Fresco initialization within ReactNative happens on a thread, Fresco.initialize() happens on main thread. Their order are not guaranteed. So our custom configuration is not always applied.

```java
reactInstanceManager.addReactInstanceEventListener(reactContext -> {
    ...
    ImagePipelineConfig imagePipelineConfig = 
    FrescoModule.getDefaultConfigBuilder(reactContext)
        .setExecutorSupplier(new CustomFrescoExecutorSupplier())
        .build();

    Fresco.initialize(application, imagePipelineConfig);
    ...
});
```

Can you help on what should be the right way to set custom configuration based on the default config builder?